# GWT ViewWithUiHandlers with DialogBox Uibinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform

I have been extending all my Views with ViewWithUiHandlers. So, from the View to invoke a presenter method I call

```
 getUiHandlers().OnUserSelect();
```

How do i get the getUiHandlers() when one of view has to extend DialogBox, as a class can't have multiple extends.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `PopupViewWithUiHandler`

Comment: I have tried the PopupViewWithUiHandler but i couldn't get the DialogBox functionality working,  that might be because of my lack of knowledge. Can you direct me to some examples which are implemented with PopupViewWithUiHandler UiBinder ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a basic popup. First, you'll have to create a `PresenterWidget` associated to your `PopupViewWithUiHandler`:

```
 public class MyPopupPresenter extends PresenterWidget<MyPopupPresenter.MyView>
        implements MyPopupUiHandlers {
    public interface MyView extends PopupView, HasUiHandlers<MyPopupUiHandlers> {
    }

    @Inject
    public MyPopupPresenter(EventBus eventBus,
                            MyView view) {
        super(eventBus, view);

        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }
}
```

Here's your `PopupViewWithUiHandlers`:

```
public class MyPopupView extends PopupViewWithUiHandlers<MyPopupUiHandlers>
        implements MyPopupPresenter.MyView, {
    public interface Binder extends UiBinder<PopupPanel, MyPopupView> {
    }

    @Inject
    public MyPopupView(Binder binder,
                       EventBus eventBus) {
        super(eventBus);

        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

And here's the UiBinder associated to your `PopupViewWithUiHandlers`. Notice the `<g:PopupPanel>`:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:PopupPanel>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            ...
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:PopupPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And, you can show the popup by calling `addToPopupSlot(myPopupPresenter)` in the parent `Presenter`:

```
public class MyPresenter extends Presenter<MyPresenter.MyView, MyPresenter.MyProxy>       implements MyUiHandlers {
    public interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<MyUiHandlers> {
    }

    @ProxyStandard
    @NameToken(NameTokens.myNameToken)
    public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<MyPresenter> {
    } 

    private final MyPopupPresenter myPopupPresenter;

    @Inject
    public MyPresenter(EventBus eventBus,
                       MyView view,
                       MyProxy proxy,
                       MyPopupPresenter myPopupPresenter) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.MainContentSlot);

        this.myPopupPresenter = myPopupPresenter;

        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }

    private void showPopup() {
        addToPopupSlot(myPopupPresenter); // this will show your popup
    }
}
```